# disable dialog webbrowser delphi

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

how to prevent the appearance of the dialog box This document has changed. save changes? which occurs in the transition when webbrowser about: blank

Thank you so much. did so

```
  Browser.Navigate ('about: blank');
  DesignMode (false ,'');
  Browser.OnNavigateComplete2: = NavigateComplite;

procedure NavigateComplite (ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
begin
  DesignMode (true ,'');
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think wich you are using the [`designMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752573%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property from the  [`IHTMLDocument2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574%28VS.85%29.aspx) Interface in your code.

you can disable the dialog box setting this property to 'Off'.

try this code before to change to the new page

```
(WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).designMode := 'off';
WebBrowser1.Stop;
```